Is there a formula relating the rate/speed a black hole event horizon will grow, to the density of the medium surrounding it?
I am thinking about the average density of the space around the black hole, not the density immediately adjacent to the event horizon which might be different. It will probably be best to model the matter contributing to the density as gas or dust.
I am sure the detailed mechanics of matter falling into a black hole are complex but it might be possible to take more of a thermodynamic approach to this question, avoiding these details.
I have conjectured that if the density outside the event horizon were to rise to the density inside the event horizon, the black hole would expand at the speed of light. It would be interesting to see how this conjecture fairs.

For a black hole, there is no "density inside the event horizon", except at the actual singularity, the density of which cannot be reached (since that would immediately create another singularity). The vacuum Schwarzschild solution still holds for $r < 2M$.

I have heard this. But surely the black hole has a mass and a volume inside the event horizon. Does that not define a density?

the standard interpretation of GR says that all mass and energy is concentrated at a single point, the volume of which is either $0$ or undefined. So, no.

But surely still an average density inside the event horizon? Even if nowhere actually has that density?

This would be entirely unphysical to assume. If you took a mass $M$ and compressed it into a radius of $r = 2GM/c^2$ , the resulting object would always undergo complete gravitational collapse and form a singularity.

Yes, you can calculate an effective density inside the event horizon, even though the interior of the BH is mostly vacuum. See https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator

It might be better to think of matter contributing to the density as a tornado, not dust.

"... the average density of the space around the black hole..." Spacetime is immaterial. It cannot have a density.

@paulina "the standard interpretation ..." No, it is a popular misinterpretation. Singularity is not a point in space and, by the way, it is non-dimensional, so it cannot have volume.

The best definition of the BH singularity I have ever heard is the motto of the submarine crew in the book "Dark Transit" by Michael DiMercurio: "It never happened. We were never there."

Perhaps I meant the density of the space at the moment, or the instant before, it collapses into a black hole. But still no answers!

@JohnHobson What do you mean with the density of space?

The mass of matter in a given volume.

So you think of a star on the verge of becoming a black hole. As a model you could use a static spherically symmetric fluid sphere of constant (energy) density (the Schwarzschild interior solution) for the radius infinitesimal above $9/8 r_{S}$. Then see what happens when the radius becomes exactly $9/8r_{S}$. Is that what you want?

This is all a bit tangential to the main question. So the average density  of a large volume outside the event horizon is simply the mass (mainly of the matter) divided by the volume. I am also assuming there is a density defined by the mass of the black hole, wherever that mass might reside, divided by the volume inside the event horizon.

I am afraid it is more complicated than you think. The best explanation is in the answer here and in the paper, Chapter 3 "What is the volume of a black hole? "

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@JanG Perhaps you are overcomplicating things. Yes, to an observer inside a black hole, volume is complex, especially if you assume a singularity. But to the outside observer, surely a black hole simply takes up 3-dimensional space equal to 4/3 pi r cubed?

@JohnHobson It is not me but the physics. Behind the black hole event horizon there is no euclidean space.

@JanG. Quite. I am sure that is right. But the volume of Euclidean space that a black hole occupies  is surely not in dispute?

@JohnHobson Unfortunately yes, in contrast to the area of the event horizon. The "radius" $r$ is not a distance from the center, but a root of the inverse Gaussian curvature of the event horizon which is its intrinsic property of that two-sphere. Space is immaterial. You cannot measure it.
